# How to save the Dicom tags in any dicom image?

Tags: python, pydicom

I am new to python and writing a simple python script using pydicom module.
I'd like to edit the tags in existing MR dicom image, I have added the code I think is required for the tags but I am unable to save that dicom file.
Furthermore I suspect the code might not be complete to achieve my purpose.

This is my code, I'd appreciate if you find something to complete:

```
import pydicom
from pydicom.data import get_testdata_files
from pydicom.dataset import Dataset, FileDataset
filename = get_testdata_files("1.dcm")[0]
ds = pydicom.dcmread(filename)
ds.add_new(0x00180020, 'GR', '1')
ds.add_new(0x00180021, 'MP', '2')
ds.save_as(filename)
```

So I've to issues with that file:
- This dicom file can't be saved.
- The code might be not sufficient for my purpose.

Comment: What happens instead? How did you determine that it doesn’t work as you expect?

Comment: Restructured Text a bit. Question is a bit diffuse as it's about two issues, perhaps in future questions you can be a bit more targeted. Perhaps you can edit the question by yourself too, to explain the problems with saving this file.
Did you check your file-rights in the system? Perhaps the files are write-protected for you? Is it possible that editing existing files is not good practice? Probably it's better to create an own project folder.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for looking into problem..
Now i have solved the problem...
Actually the script i had written was not correct, as i was trying to fetch the image data from the directory, and i was trying to call my image saved on my computer.
So random errors were coming.
Now i have edited the script and it is working fine for adding new tags to my image

Comment: It's good that you solved the problem yourself - perhaps you can share what you ended up with, so that others who find your question can have a look at the solution?

Comment: Hello Grismar, I have attached my code in comments to Emma.. Kindly go through the code from there. Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to another discussion elsewhere? If so, can you link to it? There's no Emma here that I can see...

Comment: This answer is even more puzzling than the question